# Justify text on QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm preparing a map with more than 50 sites listed. Such sites are labeled with numbers and I would like to add a text box at the bottom of the map with the full site name's list. However, it seems that there is no "justify text" option in QGIS Print Composer.

Does anyone has a suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: Just to clarify - you're referring to an attribute table in the print composer? Not a label or other print composer item?

Comment: Hi, actually I'm referring to a label, that I would like to use as a text box (since QGIS does not seem to have an "add text box" option in the Print Composer).

Answer (score 5):

You can use "Render as HTML" and add a `<div>` tag:

```html
<div style="text-align: justify;">Your text</div>
```

[image: Justified]

Comment: It haad crossed my mind, but I'm not very html savy and still had not manage to give it a try. Will try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can justify the text in the print composer.  Once you've created the text box, under "Item Properties" tab, expand "Appearance" if it isn't already, and you have the option to change the horizontal and vertical alignment of the text within the text box.

Comment: I've tried it and there is no such option. I'm using QGIS 2.10 - is this a feature of newer versions?

Comment: I've just checked the release notes and this has been available since 2.8: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog28/index.html#feature-label-item-margins

Comment: I've checked again and the only avaliable options are:
Left, Center and Right for horizontal alignment and Top, Middle and Bottom for vertical alignment. No Justified option...

Comment: My mistake I've confused my alignment types. You're right there is no "justify" option. You'll probably have to play around with the text to make it look justified. There is a feature request (#8731) asking for justified text but that was 2 years ago.  Maybe you want to re-raise the issue.

Comment: OK, just as I thought, then. Thanks for the input!